# Need to snap multiple polygons so no gaps

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is there a tool to snap together multiple polygons so no gaps? Not polylines, but polygons. I have multiple polygons covering 8,100 sq. ft of territory for separate utility shape files; it took 3 days to create 15 polygons but it will take me a week to edit all the gaps out of area! Please tell me ArcMap 9.3.1 has a tool for this!

Comment: How much space exists between the gaps (e.g. 0.001m, 5m, etc)?

Answer (score 5):

1). The safest way to do this is to place your data in a *File Geodatabase* and run *Geodatabase Topology* to identify the issues.  For example, one would set up the topology with the rules "Must Not Have Gaps" and Must Not Overlap".  In many cases then one can then fix the identified errors using the built-in tools, or opt to manually edit the changes.  However, there is a caveat to this - you will need a *Standard/ArcEditor* or *Advanced/ArcInfo* ArcGIS license.

2). If one only has a *Basic/ArcView* ArcGIS license, one could still use Topology, however it will be *Map* Topology.  This route has has less opportunities to automate solutions, but can still do the job.  http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=637&pid=632&topicname=Creating_a_map_topology

3).  Besides topology, a "tried and true" manual process for filling gaps that may speed things up is this:  *Dissolve* (geoprocessing tool) your polygons into a new layer, then edit this new layer so it covers the entire extent where there are gaps.  Now use the *Erase* geoprocessing tool to subtract your original polygon layer from the Dissolved one to end up with the slivers from the gaps.  Go into editing mode, select the resulting polygons, then hit the *Explode* button on the Editing toolbar to make all the sliver polygons singlepart (or use the geoprocessing tool to do this).  Run the *Merge* geoprocessing tool to create a new layer with your original polygons and the singlepart slivers.  Open the attribute table and sort by area.  Find the lowest area one, select it, zoom to it.  Use the *Editing toolbar* tools and pulldown to resolve it (typically select two polygons and on the pulldown *Merge*).  Repeat until all resolved.

4).  A riskier but useful option to fix is to use the *Eliminate (Data Management)* geoprocessing tool.  This tool eliminates slivers by merging small ones to larger ones based on criteria you set.  It is risky, though, in that it can sometimes merge data you don't want merged, so make a copy of your data before trying it.  You may have to do several tries before finding the settings that accomplish what you want.  When it does work, it can be a real time saver.  One caveat - one needs an *Advanced/ArcInfo* license to use it.  http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=eliminate_%28data_management%29

Answer (score 3):

I. The earliest alternative is to create a database with a topology (GAPS and OVERLAPS) and corrected in edit mode with the tool "Fix Errors" and fill in the gaps.

II. Another way is to use the "identity" tool (toolboxes):

[image]

Select correctly the layers... for example: Catastro and Distrito (state, province or country, etc.)

My project:

[image]

[image]

The output layer you can copy the polygon fill in your gaps (Fid = -1) in your working layer. Active the editing (Advanced Edit Tools - Explode Multipart Features) and finally clean your polygons (merge your gaps to polygons or delete the gaps innecesary)

In my Project the result is polygons of Roads and Rivers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Integrate (Data Management) should do the job (see http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=integrate_%28data_management%29). Mind their usage tips, though: back up your polygons first!

It's kind of automation on top of the first approach mentioned by Chris.